# How to concat strings inside ngOptions?

Tags: angularjs

Just curious if we can perform text concatenation inside `ng-options`.

```
<select
      ...
    ng-options="i.month | dnrMonthName + i.year for i in vmAdd.options.allMonths">
</select>
```

So as to get a drop down list filled with values like:

> May 2015

Is it possible? How to write the `ng-options` then?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. Here's a conceptual example - I'm sure you could adjust it to your specific object model:

```
<select ng-model="selectedItem"
        ng-options="item as (item.prop1 + ' ' + item.prop2) for item in items">
</select>
```

**EDIT:**
If you need to further apply some filter, you could do like so:

```
ng-options="item as ((item.prop1 | uppercase) + ' ' + item.prop2) for item in items"
```

Comment: I believe it should be `item as ( item.prop1 + ‘ ’ + item.prop2)...`, not `in`. And the real problem is I want to add a filter in one of the values. Like `item as (item.month | monthName + ' ' + item.year)...` How can we use the angular filter?

Comment: @Blaise, added the filter option